# DataSourceRealm not working since changing from JDBCRealm in Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I am attempting to upgrade an existing web application to run on Tomcat 10.1 from Tomcat 9.0 where it works fine. My web application currently uses JDBCRealm but this appears to now be deprecated with Tomcat 10.1 and are now advised to use DataSourceRealm instead.

I have attempted to follow the instructions on the Apache website to use the DataSourceRealm instead and upgraded both my context.xml and server.xml however my authentication isn't now working.

Here is my context.xml file:

```
<Context path="/TASSU"> <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm" connectionName="root" connectionPassword="sesame" 
 connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login_details" debug="99" driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
 roleNameCol="Rolename" userCredCol="Password" userNameCol="Username" userRoleTable="userrole" userTable="userpass"/>
```

And here is the realm information within my server.xml file:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
       resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm" connectionName="root" connectionPassword="sesame" 
 connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login_details" debug="99" driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
 roleNameCol="Rolename" userCredCol="Password" userNameCol="Username" userRoleTable="userrole" userTable="userpass"/>
```

Here is the error that is being displayed in the logs:

```
25-Jan-2023 10:13:50.699 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-23] org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm.open Exception performing authentication
```

Can anyone see at first glance what the issue could be here? Have I set these two files up correctly?